# Confidence interval for a coefficient with small N

Tags: confidence-interval, small-sample

I have a question about the confidence interval of the estimator in a multiple linear regression. Here below you can find my model:

```
lm(formula = GDP.per.head ~ PISA.math + Quality, data = Dataset)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-23954  -5958  -2253   1754  36712 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate     Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         -82346.8       82988.5       -0.992      0.334220    
PISA.math            201.8         169.5          1.190      0.249504    
Quality[T.high]      29603.3       7383.0         4.010      0.000822 ***
Quality[T.medium]   22158.0        7535.9         2.940      0.008748 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Residual standard error: 12880 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.5798, Adjusted R-squared: 0.5098 
F-statistic:  8.28 on 3 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.001134
```

If I want to calculate the confidence interval at significance level 95% of the estimation / coefficient:

- Can I say that the confidence interval for the predictor "Quality high" is `29603.3 + or - 1.96 x 7383`?
- Or, because of the small sample size (n=22), do I have to consider a different quantile than 1.96? For example, should I be using the quantile for the t-distribution at 95% for 18 DF (i.e., 1.734)?

Comment: Because you're using `R`, you can easily reverse-engineer this output: your question essentially asks whether (for instance) 0.000822 is computed as `pt(-29603.3/7383, 18)*2` or `pnorm(-29603.3/7383)*2`. Try them!

Comment: You may wish to also consider the first example at the bottom of the help on `confint` while you consider whuber's comment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers. So 0.000822 is computed as pt(-29603.3/7383, 18)*2
[1] 0.0008219592
So now that I know that pt(-29603.3/7383, 18)*2 computes 0.000822 how can I calculate the confidence interval ?